# Linq code to select one item

Tags: c#, linq

I find myself writing a lot of code like this to select one item that matches

```
var item = (from x in Items where x.Id == 123 select x).First();
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing it or is this as concise as I'm going to get?

EDIT: Should have said "Cleaner way using linq syntax". I was already aware of the lambda syntax and it's starting to look like this is actually the only way. I did get some useful info though, so thanks to everyone who replied.

Comment: Personally I avoid `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()` IF I know the data is already unique (for example from a database that has that constraint, etc), since `Single()` forces it to scan the rest of the list to find a possible duplicate, but that's me.  If you need to enforce your uniqueness at this point, use `Single()` family, if not, use `First()` family.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Depends how much you like the linq query syntax, you can use the extension methods directly like:

```
var item = Items.First(i => i.Id == 123);
```

And if you don't want to throw an error if the list is empty, use `FirstOrDefault` which returns the default value for the element type (`null` for reference types):

```
var item = Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 123);

if (item != null)
{
    // found it
}
```

`Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()` can also be used, but if you are reading from a database or something that already guarantees uniqueness I wouldn't bother as it has to scan the list to see if there's any duplicates and throws.  `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` stop on the first match, so they are more efficient.

Of the `First()` and `Single()` family, here's where they throw:

- `First()` - throws if empty/not found, does not throw if duplicate
- `FirstOrDefault()` - returns default if empty/not found, does not throw if duplicate
- `Single()` - throws if empty/not found, throws if duplicate exists
- `SingleOrDefault()` - returns default if empty/not found, throws if duplicate exists

Comment: I think you are missing two equals signs there.  Should be `i.Id == 123`

Answer (score 21):

[FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) or [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) might be useful, depending on your scenario, and whether you want to handle there being zero or more than one matches:

> FirstOrDefault: Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found.
>
> SingleOrDefault: Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default
> value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if
> there is more than one element in the sequence

I don't know how this works in a linq 'from' query but in lambda syntax it looks like this:

```
var item1 = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123);
var item2 = Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123);
```

Comment: which one is the most efficient in terms on DB time? If i had a varchar I wanted an exact match but possible there could be none?

Comment: The accepted answer addresses this in full, but essentially FirstOrDefault stops as soon as it finds a match, but SingleOrDefault must examine the whole list to ensure there is **exactly one** match.

Answer (score 15):

Just to make someone's life easier, the linq query with lambda expression

```
(from x in Items where x.Id == 123 select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

does result in an SQL query with a 
`select top (1)` in it.

Comment: Where's the lambda expression?

Answer (score 14):

These are the preferred methods:

```
var item = Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123);
```

Or

```
var item = Items.Single(x => x.Id == 123);
```

Comment: Thanks - so in this situation there is no linq notation and I need to use lambdas?

Comment: That's pretty good.  I haven't really used linq a lot, so I'm not sure I was even aware of these methods.

Comment: Single method checks that the return value is unique. So if your collection is large it can take lot of times. First method just returns the first element that match the predicate.

Comment: @wageoghe James' answer doesn't use linq - the Single and SingleOrDefault methods are part of the IEnumerable implementation.

Answer (score 9):

That can better be condensed down to this.

`var item = Items.First(x => x.Id == 123);`

Your query is currently collecting all results (and there may be more than one) within the enumerable and then taking the first one from *that* set, doing more work than necessary.

Single/SingleOrDefault are worthwhile, but only if you want to iterate through the entire collection and verify that the match is unique in addition to selecting that match. First/FirstOrDefault will just take the first match and leave, regardless of how many duplicates actually exist.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the extension method syntax:

```
var item = Items.Select(x => x.Id == 123).FirstOrDefault();
```

Other than that, I'm not sure how much more concise you can get, without maybe writing your own specialized "First" and "FirstOrDefault" extension methods.

Comment: I don't think this is the intended behavior. This Select instruction returns (actually don't, but it selects for return) a collection of bool, one for each element of Items, the first of what is returned as item, that becomes simply a bool. Use the solution of Chris Hannon

Comment: Perhaps you mean `Where` as opposed to `Select`, which has already been stated, but this answer is incorrect. Select in c# changes the results to IEnumerable<bool>, so you're getting a `bool` for the first item `x.Id == 123`

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you what worked for me:

```
int id = int.Parse(insertItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[insertItem.ItemIndex]["id_usuario"].ToString());

var query = user.First(x => x.id_usuario == id);
tbUsername.Text = query.username;
tbEmail.Text = query.email;
tbPassword.Text = query.password;
```

My id is the row I want to query, in this case I got it from a radGrid, then I used it to query, but this query returns a row, then you can assign the values you got from the query to textbox, or anything, I had to assign those to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the specific Id for that table and if you need to match multiple conditions to get the unique value, we can do something like this,

```
var item = Items.
      .Where(x => x.Name== "Name you are looking for")
      .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the first element from the `Items` if that condition matches.
If you are sure that the `Items` consist of a unique element we can use FirstOrDefault() as it will be faster.

We can also use `SingleOrDefault()` instead or `FirstOrDefault()` but it will keep on looking for the second identical element before returning the value. This might make some delay if we are querying a big database table. If we are sure that the list is unique it is better to use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault()` does not "keep on looking until the end of the list". It only checks if there's not a second item.

Comment: I think to check for the second item, it has to "keep on looking until the end of the list". I might be thinking wrong, can you explain more?

Comment: Oh, I see, so if the second item is not at the end of the list, it will not be looking until the end. It will just throw the exception if it found the second element.