# LINQ: Most Efficient Where Condition When Selecting a Single Item out of a Million

Tags: c#, linq

**The assumption**
There is around a million items in database and a stored procedure that 
**returns all items**.

Without changing the stored procedure, what is the most efficient where condition to return a single item?

**Attempts**:

```
var item = db.GetInfo().Where(i => i.url == url).Select(i => i.ID).FirstOrDefault();
var item = db.GetInfo().Where(i => i.ProductType == 5 && i.url == url).Select(i => i.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @DavidL The data is in memory at that point, so the DB indexes aren't relevant.

Comment: @DavidL: This doesn't use indexes either way.  The filter is applied to the output of a stored procedure.

Comment: So you have a stored procedure that returns _millions_ items? I would concentrate on this not on how to make your where more efficient

Comment: @Servy: I wouldn't make that assumption.  `db` implies an EF instance, which is most likely an `IQueryable`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's not an assumption.   OP says it's a "stored procedure".

Comment: @recursive: EF can be backed by stored procedures, and it can still be lazy loading.  The only material difference between an ordinary query and an SP in this context are the words "CREATE PROCEDURE."

Comment: @RobertHarvey It'll dever execution of the query until it is enumerated, yes, but it still cannot apply any subsequent operations in the DB; they're applied in memory.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Sure, but there's still no way for the `IQueryable<>` implemented by the stored procedure's result to make any use of an index.

Comment: Agree, I see what you're both saying.

Comment: Technically, neither of these statements 'returns a single item', nor do they necessarily return the same sequence for all possible inputs.

Comment: Can you please clarify why regular "C# linq return single item" approach (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809745/linq-code-to-select-one-item - `FirstOrDefault`) did not work for you and you need "Most Efficient Where condition"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, this Q was not about working or not working, it is about efficiency with limitations that is tied to a real world assumption

Comment: Both of your examples are `O(n)`.  It's not about the `where` condition; you'll need more than that to get better performance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, correct and the owner of the selected answer kindly responded to the request and covered this part.

Comment: usefulBee [edit] post to clarify that your post about efficiency and you actually know how to select single item. I.e. code you've shown does not even "select single item" (as commented by @IanMercer). Also generally performance related questions should include some measurements and goal (read [Horses by Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) for guidance).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, fixed by adding FirstOrDefault(). The title of the question speaks of efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> most efficient where condition to return a single item

**With the assumption that the SP "returns all items"**, if all you want is the first item that answers a condition then just use `FirstOrDefault`. If such an item exists it will return it the moment it is found. In the worst case it will be in o(n)

```
var item = db.GetInfo().FirstOrDefault(i => i.url == url)?.ID;
var item = db.GetInfo().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductType == 5 && i.url == url)?.ID
```

*Both queries have the same efficiency of o(n)* - **If this would be** executed in the database the existence of indexes on these fields would have made a difference. For example if the `ProductType` field had an index then the second query would have been more efficient

With no doubt the better option will be that this will happen in database and not in memory... but if that can't be changed..

Comment: This is faster because it can sometimes exit early, without iteration all million records.

Comment: But how this compares to db.GetInfo().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductType == 5 && i.url == url)?.ID; What makes this less efficient?

Comment: @GiladGreen http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fastest+gun - posting half-ready answer has its price :) and there is no way to notify voters about change - so negative votes stick (not my downvote - but very well could have been)