# How do I return a element using LINQ query from an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

I have an ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<NurDeviceWatcherInfo> KnownDevices = new ObservableCollection<NurDeviceWatcherInfo>();
```

`NurDeviceWatcherInfo` has these string properties: *Address, ConnState, Info, Name, Spec, SpecStr, Tag, TransportType*.

What I am trying to use is:

```
NurDeviceWatcherInfo device = from NurDeviceWatcherInfo in KnownDevices 
                                where NurDeviceWatcherInfo.Name.Contains("NUR") 
                                select new NurDeviceWatcherInfo();
```

For which I receive the following error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'NurApiDotNet.UWP.NurDeviceWatcherInfo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Note that the problem is exactly the same for _any_ `IEnumerable`, not only `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq code to select one item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809745/linq-code-to-select-one-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using :

```
device = KnownDevices.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("NUR")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can just use ``firstOrDefault``, like `device = KnownDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("NUR"));`